# Magento 2 Enterprise edition, get all custom attributes of product in the observer

Tags: magento2, event-observer, custom-attributes

My store has many GroupProduct and each one has many virtual products. This virtual products have custom attributes and some are required and some aren't.

[MyModule]/Setup/InstallData.php

```
$eavSetup->addAttribute(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
        'iesep_sigla',
        [
            'type' => 'text',
            'group' => 'IESE',
            'backend' => '',
            'frontend' => '',
            'label' => 'Sigla IESE',
            'input' => 'text',
            'class' => '',
            'source' => '',
            'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
            'visible' => true,
            'required' => true,
            'user_defined' => false,
            'default' => '',
            'searchable' => true,
            'filterable' => false,
            'filterable_in_search' => false,
            'comparable' => false,
            'visible_on_front' => false,
            'used_in_product_listing' => false,
            'used_for_promo_rules' => true,
            'unique' => false,
            'apply_to' => ''
        ]
    );

    $eavSetup->addAttribute(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
        'iesep_idioma',
        [
            'type' => 'varchar',
            'group' => 'IESE',
            'frontend' => '',
            'label' => 'Idioma',
            'input' => 'select',
            'class' => '',
            'source' => '',
            'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
            'backend' => 'Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Backend\ArrayBackend',
            'visible' => true,
            'required' => false,
            'user_defined' => false,
            'default' => '',
            'searchable' => false,
            'filterable' => true,
            'filterable_in_search' => true,
            'comparable' => false,
            'visible_on_front' => false,
            'used_in_product_listing' => false,
            'unique' => false,
            'apply_to' => ''
        ]
    );
```

**The goal is to save some of the product attributes in sales_order_item table.**

product attribute -> quote_item -> sales_order_item

When the GroupProduct  is added to the cart the observer assigned to the event sales_quote_item_set_product is being executed for each item.

Then when I try to get a product attribute that is not required with the method $observer->getProduct()->getData('iesep_idioma') I get a null value. If I try to get an attribute that is required I do get the value.

**

### How do I load the attributes that I need without loading the whole object?

**

[MyModule]/etc/events.php

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
<event name="sales_quote_item_set_product">
    <observer
            name="product_point_quote"
            instance="Alfa9\CatalogPreview\Observer\salesQuoteItemSetCustomAttribute"/>
</event>
</config>
```

[MyModule]/Observer/salesQuoteItemSetCustomAttribute.php

```
<?php
namespace Alfa9\CatalogPreview\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Eav\Api\AttributeRepositoryInterface;

class salesQuoteItemSetCustomAttribute implements ObserverInterface
{

protected $eavAttributeRepository;
private $_productRepo;

public function __construct(
    AttributeRepositoryInterface $eavAttributeRepository,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository $productRepo
) {
    $this->eavAttributeRepository = $eavAttributeRepository;
    $this->_productRepo = $productRepo;
}

public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
{
    $iesep_idioma = $observer->getProduct()->getData('iesep_idioma'); //return null
    $iesep_sigla = $observer->getProduct()->getData('iesep_sigla'); //return value

    //More code here

}
}
```

[image]
[image]